# Sort an array with an ACF meta key

Tags: sort

I get an Array from wordpress get_categories and i need to sort it with a value that is inside an ACF field.
This value is composed like this : number | year , for example 2 | 2017

I need to sort with number (that can be 1, 2, 3...), this will determine my order rank.

To get my categories array i do :

```
  $args = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'category',
    'hide_empty' => 0
  );
  $c = get_categories($args);
```

And i think i must add a for each after that with a usort but i don't know how to do.
To get my  ACF field i could do this:

```
 get_field('millesime', 'category_'.$cat->term_id);
```

And this to extract the number:

```
 substr ( get_field('millesime', 'category_'.$cat->term_id),0,1)
```

But my problem is that i don't know how to make it work with USORT.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

In you $args you need to make sure to order your categories like so:

```
 $args = array(
'taxonomy' => 'category',
'orderby' => 'date',
'order'   => 'DESC',
'hide_empty' => 0
  ); $c = get_categories($args);
```

Did you make a custom taxonomy and use that within ACF?